# How much is known about the action functional for small noise diffusions with general volatility coefficients?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, large-deviations

Let $W$ be a d-dimensional Brownian motion, and for every $\varepsilon > 0$, let $X^\varepsilon$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX^\varepsilon_t = b(X^\varepsilon_t) \, dt + \varepsilon \sigma (X^\varepsilon_t) \, dW_t$$

on $[0, T]$ with some deterministic initial condition $x_0$.

Consider the distribution $\mu_\varepsilon$ of $X^\varepsilon$ conditional on exiting an open set $\Omega$ containing $x_0$. By Friedlin-Wentzell theory, it is known that $\mu$ satisfies a large deviation principle as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

**Question:** How much is known about the rate function $I$ of this large deviation principle on $C[0, T]$? In particular, is it given by an "action functional"? That is, is $I(\phi)$ given by an integral functional of the form

$$I(\phi) = \int_0^T F(t, \phi(t), \phi'(t)) \, dt \; \text{for } \phi \text{ absolutely continuous};$$
$$+\infty, \text{ otherwise }?$$

If so, is the explicit form of this action functional known?

Comment: This is well known. See Dembo-Zeitouni Theorem 5.6.7. on page 214

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I need! @user479223